# What are some drawbacks to Interac's e-transfer auto-deposit option?

Tags: canada, money-transfer, online-payment, deposits

As a user, what are the drawbacks for Interac e-transfer auto-deposit and what I should consider before using it?

Comment: I expect the close-voters don't know what Interac is and are thinking it's one particular bank's option. It's a Canada-wide multi bank payment system and this question, now properly tagged, is on topic.

Answer (score 5):

About the only drawback is that you can't choose where the money goes. My son in law has only one bank account; he has auto deposit on. My daughter has several: one with the bank that holds their mortgage, one with another bank that is her general purpose operating account, and of course a savings account. She might want to deposit an e-transfer into any one of these accounts, so she doesn't use auto deposit and she makes the choice each time.

If you only have one account, there's no downside; go for it.

Answer (score 3):

Kate's answer is good, but there is one other scenario where this may be disadvantageous.  You may or may not want to actually accept the Interac e-transfer... Perhaps someone has sent you too much money (say a friend) or someone has not sent you enough money (perhaps relating to a business transaction).  Automatically accepting the money may commit you, to some extent at least, to something you hadn't agreed to.

Comment: Possibly also if it's a scam, as in here:  https://money.stackexchange.com/q/158554/32127